# Anyone experience marrying in Japan?

Tags: japan, canadian-citizens, weddings

I’m planning to bring my birth certificate to Japan because the ward office requires you to have original copy of it in order to get married. Would it be possible if I bring it just for that purpose? I’m only staying in Japan for a month and get back to Canada to start my gf’s immigration process so she can live here in Canada with me. Will I have trouble with the Japanese immigration? My other option is sending it through DHL or FedEx to my gf’s address.

Comment: I don't think carrying a birth certificate is an issue, just make sure you have all the paperwork (see this [page](https://jp.usembassy.gov/services/marriage/marriage-in-japan/) from the US Embassy (most still applies) and then contact the Canadian embassy in Japan for the guidances that apply to you)

Comment: Make sure you get a certificate of no impediment.

Comment: I flew to Asia for a pandemic wedding that almost didn't happen because they demanded a certificate of no impediment and Canada doesn't do those. Luckily a different clerk accepted a notarized declaration. Investigating that in advance is likely to be worthwhile.